# Create an option Menu on Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made an option menu in my application and for some reason it works on one of my smartphones and not the other. The smartphone the option menu works on is android lollipop 5.0 the smartphone it doesn't work on is jellybean 4.1. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it but I need the option menu to work on both phones. ANyone any ideas on why this is happening
My Code is as fallows
MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_Menu) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="saveourcar.soc.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_Menu"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Menu"
        app:showAsAction="never" >
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/instructions"
            android:title="Instructions"
            android:icon="@drawable/rench"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/hotels"
            android:title="Hotels"
            android:icon="@drawable/hotel"/>

    </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

[image][image]

Comment: Old smartphones have a physical buttom for "Open menu", old android recognize this and hide the "3 balls icon"...  try add this to the menu layout: android:showAsAction="always"

Comment: your bang on. Is there anyway I could get the "3 balls" icon though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In onCreateView method:

```
setHasOptionsMenuEnabled(true);
```

or this on menu layout:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: The first option gave me an error and the second didn't work.